# Fundamental Solution for this Problem Solving Question

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This question appeared in my math/ problem solving competition. It goes like this : Six competitors in a chess tournament played against each other once only. (That totals fifteen games). A win is worth one point, a draw is worth half a point and a loss is worth no points. The fourth player scored 2 points and the sixth player scored 1 point. There were no equal scores, while the person who came first had no losses and one draw. Work out the second players score.

I have figured out that the 5th person must have had 1 and a half points and also know that the second person must have in between 3 and 4 points. However, I cannot proceed from here and would like to appeal to someone for their insight on how to solve such problems.

P.S I do not know what to tag this post. If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you know the number of points won by positions 1,4,5,6.... how many points are left to allocate to the remaining 2 players?

Comment: 15-4.5-2-1.5-1=6

Answer (score 2):

15 points awarded in total

points by position ...
    1 - 4.5 pts
    2 - x pts
    3 - y pts
    4 - 2 pts
    5 - 1.5 pts
    6 - 1 pt

so $x+y=15-9=6$

the only possibility involving no equal scores is $x=3.5; y=2.5$